# Efficiently converting maps?

Tags: java, algorithm, list, dictionary

I want to convert a `HashMap<Character, Integer>` into a `TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Character>>` in an efficient manner, but I'm having trouble conceptualizing it. Anything I might try?

Comment: What's your conversion algorithm?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I imagine that he wants to "reverse" the mapping on this map.

Comment: I'm looking for a method to do this. I hardly think it'll take much code, but I can't really conceptualize it.

Comment: Since `TreeMap` has `O(log n)` find and insert, `ArrayList` has amortized `O(1)` append and `HashMap` has `O(n)` iteration, it's easy to solve this problem in `O(n log n)`. Is that good enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reverse the mapping, then you can do something like this:

```
//If still using Java 6 enter the generic types in the diamond
Map<Integer, List<Character>> treeMap = new TreeMap<>(); 
for(Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : hashMap.entrySet()) {
    Integer value = entry.getValue();
    if(treeMap.get(value) == null) {
        treeMap.put(value, new ArrayList<Character>());
    }

    List<Character> arrayList = treeMap.get(value);
    arrayList.add(entry.getKey());

    //You can convert the above into this if you want, as well:
    //   treeMap.get(value).add(entry.getKey());
}
```

Please let me know if this is what you are expecting.

Comment: This gives a "The method add(Character) is undefined for the type Integer" compiler error on the `value.add(entry.getKey());`, did I do something wrong?

Comment: @user3353751 Typo on my part; it should say `arrayList` and not `value`.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one trivial conversion:

```
TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Character>> convert(HashMap<Character, Integer> x) {
    return new TreeMap<>();
}
```

But I suspect there are additional requirements you haven't yet articulated.